# Getting bus error 10 with pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, pthreads

My command line tool keeps throwing the `bus error: 10` message. Xcode debugger shows `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` message and highlights the function call that creates the thread. Manual debugging shows that the execution flow breaks at random positions inside the thread flow. I tried another compiler (gcc), but it ended up the same. Disabling `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` doesn't help. I wrote this small example that reproduces the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


typedef struct thread_args {
    pthread_mutex_t* mutex;
} thread_args;


void* test(void* t_args) {
    printf("Thread initiated\n");
    thread_args* args = (thread_args* )t_args;
    printf("Args casted\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(args->mutex);
    printf("Mutex locked\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(args->mutex);
    printf("Mutex unlocked\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main() {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex1;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);

    thread_args args;
    args.mutex = &mutex1;

    pthread_t* thread;
    printf("Initiating a thread\n");
    pthread_create(thread, NULL, test, &args);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, in your case,

```
pthread_create(thread, NULL, test, &args);
```

at this call, `thread` is a pointer and not allocated memory. So, essentially `pthread_create()` tries to write into uninitialized memory, which creates [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Referring the man page of [`pthread_create()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create)

> Before returning, a successful call to `pthread_create()` stores the ID of the new thread in the buffer pointed to by `thread`;....

Instead, you can do

```
 pthread_t thread;
 ...
 pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test, &args);
```

Comment: I always thought this is sort of errors result in `segmentation fault`

Comment: @EliKorvigo well, almost, but not always. UB is the actual effect, segfault is the side-effect.

Comment: Well, then I'll have to allocate memory dynamically, because different threads are spawned inside many different functions, hence I can't use local variables, because I'm not going to `join` the threads. Then, how can I `free` the allocated memory without waiting for the thread to finish, i.e. without calling `join`?

Answer (score 2):

As other answers pointed out, you need to initialize your pointer `thread` which you can simply do with:

```
   pthread_t thread;
   pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test, &args);
```

> Well, then I'll have to allocate memory dynamically, because different
>   threads are spawned inside many different functions, hence I can't use
>   local variables, because I'm not going to join the threads. Then, how
>   can I free the allocated memory without waiting for the thread to
>   finish, i.e. without calling join?

No. You don't need to dynamically allocate just because you are going to spawn multiple threads. The thread identifier is no longer needed once a thread has been created So whether it's a local variable or `malloc`ed is not important. It's only needed when you need to `join` or change some characteristics of the thread -- for which you need the ID. Otherwise, you can even reuse the same thread for creating multiple threads. For example,

```
   pthread_t thread;
   for( i = 0; i<8; i++)
     pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
```

is perfectly fine. A thread can always get its own ID by calling `pthread_self()` if needed. But you *can't* pass a local variable `mutex1` to thread functions as once `main` thread exits, the `mutex1` no longer exits as thread created continues to use it. So you either need malloc `mutex1` or make it a global variable.

Another thing to do is that if you decide to let the main thread exit then you should call `pthread_exit()`. Otherwise, when the *main* thread exits (either by calling `exit` or simply `return`) then the whole process will die, meaning, all the threads will die too.

Comment: Since I always avoid global variables, the mutexes indeed are declared in the `main` function and are passed as pointers via  `thread_args` instances. The `main` function waits for all threads to finish their work, so that's okay. It's good to know that `pthread_p` instances are only used once to initiate a thread. Thank you.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Note that other point about `pthread_exit`ing in main too. Otherwise, it won't behave as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an uninitialized pointer to your `pthread_t`.   The actual storage of the `pthread_t` needs to be somewhere!

Try :

```
int main() {
   pthread_mutex_t mutex1;
   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);

   thread_args args;
   args.mutex = &mutex1;

   pthread_t thread;
   printf("Initiating a thread\n");
   pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test, &args);
   return(0);
}
```